# bootstrap img height: auto property overrides explicit height

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

For awhile I was avoiding upgrading my bootstrap-sass gem in my ruby project because of one single change :

```
height: auto;
```

inside the img element.

This property seems to override explicit height properties.

So I have an image that is width 1, height 32 and I use it as such :

```
<img height="1" width="15" src="/assets/spc.png" alt="">
```

The `height: auto;` seems to force the image to display as 15 x 480 (32 x 15 = 480).

I have tried to redefine the img element by adding in-line style in the HEAD of my HTML, (for example `img { }`) but this does not seem to help.

I am not sure what the appropriate solution is.  I use blank images around my site to create specific spaces between other elements.  I probably can do this with some other kind of element, like a div or a span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using `margin`?

you can for example:

```
.spacerdiv{

height:1px;
width:15px;
}
```

add the div in the html and define this class to them.
But that's very bad practice. adding redundant elements to DOM

or even better just define `margin`

You can do it object oriented and define things like:

```
.margin_left_part_of_site{
margin: 5px 15px;
}
```

You can then add this class to every element that must have these properties.

A jsfiddle example would allow further help.

Comment: I've asked this question another way : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891489/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-space-in-an-html-css-document

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was to use divs.  I now use divs such as :

```
.login-spc {
  display: inline-block;
  height:40px;
  width:5px;
  vertical-align: middle;  
}
```