# What is the best way to create space in an HTML/CSS document?

Tags: html, css

I have a div in which there are rows of 3 images each.  The images are all the same size.  I had been using small completely clear transparent image which I would then explicitly give height and width to form spaces between the images.  An example would be something like :

```
 div begin
 space image width=15, height=1 actual image (no explicit dimensions)
 space image width=10, height=1 actual image (no explicit dimensions)
 space image width=10, height=1 actual image (no explicit dimensions)

 space image width=900, height=20 (this is to separate rows, which should be 900 wide, space + 3 x image)

 space image width=15, height=1 actual image (no explicit dimensions)
 space image width=10, height=1 actual image (no explicit dimensions)
 space image width=10, height=1 actual image (no explicit dimensions)
 div end
```

These rows may or may not be generated via code and there are sometimes hrefs.  I realize that I could perhaps use margins/padding on the image/or anchor element to create space.  But this would require setting a class on each image.  That does not seem like a good way to go about this.  For a few reasons : the space would be inside the anchor tags, making it linkable.  I would not be opposed to using divs and using specific classes on those.  I have tried this however, and they do not seem to work as I would expect.  They create line breaks, so now the images appear in a column, and they don't seem to take up any actual space anyway.

Comment: The questions is very difficult to understand in the reference of your code. Please share the actual HTML code produced and then post your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using spacer images is rather clumsy and hardly ever needed. The simplest approach is probably to wrap all images inside `a` elements, using just `<a><img ...></a>` for those that aren’t meant to be links. Then you can set margin on the `a` element, without making the margin clickable.

You can also format the image gallery in rows of three images without making such division part of the HTML code. Example:

```
.gallery img { border: 0; margin-bottom: 20px;  }
.gallery a:nth-child(3n+1) { margin-left: 15px; }
.gallery a:nth-child(3n+2) { margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; }
.gallery a:nth-child(3n+3):after { content: "\A"; white-space: pre; }
```

This effectively makes the layout table-like, without hard-coding the division into columns in HTML. The last rule is a bit tricky (but valid) way of causing a line break after every 3rd element.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yucca42/2MgDM/)

P.S. This creates a 20px margin below the last row of images, too. If this is an issue, you can nullify it by setting `.gallery { margin-bottom: -20px }`.

Answer (score 2):

```
  How about 2 divs, one for each row. Then set the margins on those.

  <div class="row"> Your images or anchor tags</div>
  <div class="row"> Your images or anchor tags</div>
```

Then

```
 .row{
      margin-top:10px;

  }
```

or however much space you want between rows of images.

You may use divs for the images in order to position them on the screen better. Especially wanting to avoid adding a margin to an anchor tag.

```
 div.img{
     display:inline;
 }

 .firstcol{
     margin-left:15px;
 }

 .col{
     margin-left:10px;
 }
```

and

```
 <div class="img firstcol">The first image of teh row</div>
 <div class="img col">The second image of teh row</div>
```

etc.

Comment: That seems like it would work partially.  I do want the first space between the edge of the box and image to be 15, and then the next space to be 10.  Like :  | 15 IMAGE 10 IMAGE 10 IMAGE 15 |

Comment: Then create several classes. Call them row15, row10 etc depending on how much space you want. Then apply them when needed.

Comment: It's not the rows, it's the column, isn't it?  The row as a 15px space on the left, then 10px between image 1 and 2, 10px between image 2 and 3.  Then the new row occurs.

Comment: OH! I did not get that. Then use margin-left:15px etc. You can use divs if you set the display to inline.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have gotten to work :

```
.row {
  margin-left:20px;
}
.space {
  margin-left:12px;
  display: inline;
}
.row-space {
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

div class=row
  a href=x img
  div class=space /div
  a href=x img
  div class=space /div
/div

div class=row-space /div
```

I needed the display-inline to avoid a line break.  I had read and have used float: left, in the past, but this has some other side effects which are not good for this purpose.